# R SVM Predict - Error in predict.svm: test data does not match model

Tags: r, svm

I started with a data frame of 23,515 rows and 3 columns. I split the data 70/30 into training/testing. I am fitting a classification model with SVM from the e1071 package to predict variable MISSING. After I fit the model, I attempt to predict MISSING in my test set but I get the error below:

```
> ftplh_svm <- svm(MISSING ~ V1+V2, data=train_vars, type="C-classification", kernel="linear")
> p <- predict(ftplh_svm, test_vars, type="class")
Error in predict.svm(object, ...) : test data does not match model !
```

I tried removing the predicted class from the test set as recommended in another post:

```
> p <- predict(ftplh_svm, test_vars[-3], type="class")
Error in predict.svm(object, ...) : test data does not match model !
```

I also tried dropping empty levels as recommended by [Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7623055/brad), but no levels ended up being dropped and I got the same results:

```
> train_vars$V1 <- droplevels(as.factor(train_vars$V1))
> train_vars$V2 <- droplevels(as.factor(train_vars$V2))
> train_vars$MISSING <- droplevels(as.factor(train_vars$MISSING))
> test_vars$V1 <- droplevels(as.factor(test_vars$V1))
> test_vars$V2 <- droplevels(as.factor(test_vars$V2))
> test_vars$MISSING <- droplevels(as.factor(test_vars$MISSING))
> ftplh_svm <- svm(MISSING ~ V1+V2, data=train_vars, type="C-classification", kernel="linear")
> p <- predict(ftplh_svm, test_vars, type="class")
Error in predict.svm(object, ...) : test data does not match model !
```

Structure of my training set and test set:

```
> str(train_vars)
'data.frame':   16395 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 148 levels "AAC","AAL","AGP",..: 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V2  : Factor w/ 284 levels "6AR","AAC","AAL",..: 79 42 180 180 180 180 180 180 180 180 ...
 $ MISSING      : Factor w/ 2 levels "FALSE","TRUE": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
> str(test_vars)
'data.frame':   7129 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 111 levels "AAC","AAL","AGP",..: 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V2  : Factor w/ 265 levels "AAC","AAL","ABZ",..: 225 169 169 169 169 169 169 169 169 169 ...
 $ MISSING      : Factor w/ 2 levels "FALSE","TRUE": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Test to see if there are new levels in my test set (I did this for each variable):

```
> train_lev <- levels(train_vars$V1)
> test_lev <- levels(test_vars$V1)
> # these levels only exist in the test set
> new_levels <- setdiff(test_lev,train_lev)
> new_levels
character(0)
> # how many observations is it?
> obs <- which(test_vars$V1 %in% new_levels)
> length(obs)
[1] 0
```

Comment: Once your data is split into training and test you shouldn't assume all those levels have entries. A level that is present in both the training and test sets might be an empty level in one but not in the other. Once the data is split try drop empty levels using droplevels() and then compare.

Comment: Thanks @Brad - I tried this, but it doesn't seem to have worked.

Comment: SVM's require pure numeric values no? Maybe hot one encoding or a tensor input to accommodate multiple SVM's, one for each factor. Have you inputted values for all missing values? SVM's don't do missing values